# Is it possible to create an ad-hoc wi-fi connection?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, networking, realtek

I can't connect my Ubuntu client on a Wi-Fi ad-hoc connection. I tried Windows XP and 7 on server, no success. I can't use Linux on server, only Windows. Thanks.
Realtek RTL8187B.

Comment: I think it would help if you could provide some more information from logs. Look in `/var/log/` for the appropriate sections (possibly dmesg, daemon, or messages) and post them here.

Comment: So you can't connect with any machine to your Wi-Fi? I'm not sure, if I understand you right. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

I have set up an ad hoc wireless connection between a xp machine and an ubuntu. Here is what I did:

1. On ubuntu in "edit network connections -> wireless", I clicked on "add" and I gave network name "ubuntu"  and selected "ad-hoc" connection and gave a static ip and saved it. I restarted wireless by right clicking network indicator in the system tray and ticking off "wireless" and ticking it on again.
2. On xp first you need to give a static ip for wireless LAN. I turned on wireless in xp and it detected the "ubuntu" network. If it doesn't work, create a network of the same name "ubuntu" on xp, and try if it works.
3. It takes a minute or two on xp to connect to ubuntu after the detection or selection of "ubuntu" network. I have connected multiple pc having both ubuntu and xp simultaniously.
4. But even I am facing an issue. Xp won't allow ubuntu pc to access any windows services, even I couldn't ping xp from an ubuntu machine. But ubuntu will allow access to all its services for xp machines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the drivers for your wireless card are properly installed and working?

I suggest looking at this similar question: [Unable to Connect to Wireless Network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4266/unable-to-connect-to-wireless-network)

If you could update your question with the same feedback from that question, we could probably help you pinpoint a solution. :-)